# Fire event on filtering DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I want to have an event during data retrieval from a `DbSet` object.

```
dbContext.Set<BusinessObject>().AsNoTracking().Any(x => x.Property1== SomeData)
```

Upon it's execution I need to have the generated SQL. I have it from logs and `ToQueryString` method but I have to call it in everywhere before execution.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Take a look at [Entity Framework Core's interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors). You may also be interested in [an overview of logging and interception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) for Entity Framework Core. And just as a side note, please only tag your question with relevant tags, Entity Framework and Entity Framework Core are two entirely different products and in many cases not compatible

Comment: You wrote `EF6` in the title, then you tagged `EF core` in the tags, which version of `EF` do you mean exactly?

Comment: For now, lacking response, I assumed EF-core 6. With EF6 (not EFC6) it would be [Logging and intercepting database operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception).